# string termination error for c vulenerabilities

Tags: c

```
sprintf(workbuf,
        "(C)(0225,0181) %6.6s HDR REC BAD TRAN_SETL_FNUM, OFFSET %ld, LEN %ld, FILE=[%s/%s]",
        tranHdr->lu.source_path_name, offsetof(RTPN_HEADER_REC, tran_setl_fnum),
        sizeof(rtpn_hdr->tran_setl_fnum), pathPtr->inFileName, pathPtr->userFileName);
```

what is the expectation for `sprintf`. why we are getting string termination error

Comment: "Probably" unrelated: use `"%zu"` with `sizeof`

Comment: As well as the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please show the full "string termination error" message.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use `sprintf` which cannot check for a buffer overflow over `snprintf` that does.

Furthermore the conversion specifiers for values of type `size_t` should be `%zu`, not `%ld`, which are incorrect if `sizeof(size_t) != sizeof(long)` as is the case on Windows 64-bit platforms.

Truncation can be tested by comparing the return value of `snprintf` with the length of the destination array. It must be strictly less than the array length to indicate that no truncation occurred.

Answer (score 0):

What is *"string termination error"*? Nothing like this exists.

Your `workbuf` must be long enough to accompdate the string **and** the null terminating character. If workbuf is not big enough, your code will invoke undefined behaviour.

If you want to be sure that you will not invoke this UB you need to use `snprinf` function. But if the buffer will not be large enough you will not get the whole string.

If you want to know what is required length of the buffer:

```
int length = snprintf(NULL, 0,
        "(C)(0225,0181) %6.6s HDR REC BAD TRAN_SETL_FNUM, OFFSET %zu, LEN %zu, FILE=[%s/%s]",
        tranHdr->lu.source_path_name, offsetof(RTPN_HEADER_REC, tran_setl_fnum),
        sizeof(rtpn_hdr->tran_setl_fnum), pathPtr->inFileName, pathPtr->userFileName);

char workbuf[length + 1];

snprintf(workbuf, sizeof(workbuf),
        "(C)(0225,0181) %6.6s HDR REC BAD TRAN_SETL_FNUM, OFFSET %zu, LEN %zu, FILE=[%s/%s]",
        tranHdr->lu.source_path_name, offsetof(RTPN_HEADER_REC, tran_setl_fnum),
        sizeof(rtpn_hdr->tran_setl_fnum), pathPtr->inFileName, pathPtr->userFileName);
```

Also use `%zu` when printing `size_t` number